# How to create or set a variable inside Direct Database Request (DDR) filter query?

Tags: obiee

I am unable to use a [Direct Database Request](https://medium.com/red-pill-analytics/pardirect-database-request-6fa4d668bab8) (DDR) as a filter query.
The requirement is to filter postal codes in my main subject area-based query using a DDR-based query which performs a REGEXP function, explained below.

**Is there any way to define or set the value of a presentation or request variable inside my filter query?**

What other approaches could I try? 
The REGEXP function is not function-shippable to the RPD via EVALUATE() in an OBIEE analysis, due to being not supported in my NQSConfig.INI file.
And, this is an Oracle Sales Cloud instance, so I do not have access to modify my NQSConfig.INI file.

---

**What I've tried so far:**

I've created a DDR in OBIEE using the Connection Pool defined in my RPD.

This query retrieves all postal codes that are non-numeric:
`SELECT 
hz_parties.party_id,
hz_parties.postal_code
FROM 
HZ_PARTIES
where
REGEXP_INSTR(Substr(HZ_PARTIES.POSTAL_CODE,0,2), '[0-9]{2}') = 0`

This works.

But I have an OBIEE subject-area based analysis which needs a filter using operator `is based on results of another analysis`, using the DDR and matches against its `party_id` column.

This is the generated error and SQL of my main OBIEE analysis:

`Error Details
Error Codes: YQCO4T56:OPR4ONWY:U9IM8TAC:OI2DL65P
Location: saw.views.evc.activate, saw.httpserver.processrequest, saw.rpc.server.responder, saw.rpc.server, saw.rpc.server.handleConnection, saw.rpc.server.dispatch, saw.threadpool.socketrpcserver, saw.threads
Odbc driver returned an error (SQLExecDirectW).
State: HY000. Code: 10058. [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. [nQSError: 27047] Nonexistent table: "EXECUTE". (HY000)
SQL Issued: {call NQSGetLevelDrillability('SELECT "Contact"."Contact Row ID" saw_0 FROM "Sales - CRM Customers and Contacts Real Time" WHERE "Contact"."Contact Row ID" IN (SELECT saw_0 FROM (EXECUTE PHYSICAL CONNECTION POOL "CRM_OLTP"."Connection Pool" SELECT hz_parties.party_id, hz_parties.postal_code FROM HZ_PARTIES where REGEXP_INSTR(Substr(HZ_PARTIES.POSTAL_CODE,0,2), ''[0-9]{2}'') = 0 ) nqw_1 )')}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you're in a cloud product I'd say this sounds like you should open an SR :)

Comment: Except that I'm the Oracle Support Engineer :)
The question is not for a customer issue; just a curiosity to see if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: You think I didn't google you? ;-)

This isn't supported in any incarnation of Oracle Analytics. Not OBIEE, not OTBI and not OAC. Sorry.